# How to call parent's method when requiring child class?

Tags: coffeescript

I have the following hierarchy:

```
  class BaseController
    validateCloverToken: ->
      console.log 123


  module.exports = new class RetailersController extends BaseController
    getAll: (req, reply) ->
      @validateCloverToken()
```

When I try to call RetailersController in another file:

```
RetailersController = require("../controllers/retailers")
RetailersController.getAll()
```

I get the following exception:

```
TypeError: Uncaught error: this.validateCloverToken is not a function
```

Any ideas how to fix this?
I am using it within a HapiJS route:

```
{
    method: "GET"
    path: "/retailers"
    handler: RetailersController.getAll
    config:
      auth:
        strategy: "jwt"
        scope: ["a"]
      description: "Get a list of all retailers"
      tags: ["api"]
  }
```

Comment: I've tried the code you've shared and it works for me. Maybe you have pasted just some of your code and the bug is in a different place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does not work here with HapiJS. "this" was the HapiJS context. When I use a fat arrow for the getAll function everything works fine.
It should look like:

```
 getAll: (req, reply) =>
      @validateCloverToken()
```